# Records access on customer portal

Tags: customer-portal, sharing

when I create a child record linked to the parent and that child has lookup to Contact X, I want to share the parent with contact X

How can I do that?

Comment: One clarification here. Is it possible with authenticated website license with without sharing in VF page , to do editing on record which he don't have permission. Becuase actually the user wont have access to that record.

Answer (score 2):

Your order of action sounds wrong? Probably you mean something like "*when I create a child record linked to the parent and that child has lookup to Contact X, I want to share the parent with contact X*".

It doesn't look like you can achieve this with just configuration (for example criteria-based sharing rule) because these can be used only to share with Roles/Groups, not individuals. Can you use Apex managed sharing? [There's a nice example of an "after insert" trigger in the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm), you'd have to create one like that on the child object.

Another option would be to simply route all viewing / edititng of the object through VF page and controller that would have "without sharing" modifier and you'd be responsible for proper data filtering.

Comment: Yep, you are right. But my current license is "Authenticated Website" which doesn't support Apex Managed Sharing. Seems like I need customer portal manager license.

Comment: @doga were you able to find a list of all the licenses supported by apex managed sharing?